# are multiple version of the Windows SDK necessary?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I was just looking through my installed programs to free up some space, and I noticed that there are two versions of the Windows SDK, and the ASP.NET SDK. Are these 32-bit and 64-bit? The package name does not indicate that is the case, so I am wondering if I need both versions of these packages installed?

[image: add/remove programs screenshot]

As you can see in the image, `Windows SDK 10.1.10586.15` and `Windows SDK 10.0.26624`, and `ASP.NET RC1 Update 1 1.0.20204.0` and `ASP.NET RC1 Update 1 10.0.11123.0`. Since both packages were installed on the same date, I *assume* that they are 32-bit and 64-bit, but I would also *assume* that they would be named such, if that were the case.

These packages are being used for Windows 10 Universal app development in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Not entirely sure myself.  I'd be surprised if 1 was 32-bit and the other is 64.  I bet you stimply have 2 different versions - which is odd. But be certain that the Add/Remove Programs isn't lying to you. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00e145f7-d7af-4310-bceb-4ded26a1830c/rtm-known-issue-windows-sdk-version-in-setup-and-control-panel-100266270-does-not-match-the?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues

Comment: Thanks for the link. Oddly enough, there are **THREE** versions in the folder mentioned. Version 10.0.10150.0, 10.0.10240.0, and 10.0.10586.0, but no sign of 10.0.26624 anywhere. I suppose I will delete the 26624 one and see what happens.

Comment: @HansPassant I was actually referring to the Windows SDK. In the folder mentioned in the link (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\`), I had three different folders, with the versions I mentioned, no sign of version 10.0.26624 anywhere. When I uninstalled 10.0.26624, it broke my Windows 10 project, so I'm going to uninstall the other version and re-install the one Visual Studio recommends automatically to fix my project.

Comment: Windows SDK 10.0.26624 is the SDK for the first Build 10240 from Summer 2015. Windows SDK 10.1.10586.15 is the SDK for the November Update 1511

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I ended up uninstalling both versions and then just letting Visual Studio install the necessary SDK to run my project, and now I just have 10.0.26624.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am posting as an answer here from @magicandre1981 comments above, so I can close the question.

> Windows SDK 10.0.26624 is the SDK for the first Build 10240 from Summer 2015.
>
> Windows SDK 10.1.10586.15 is the SDK for the November 2015 Update 1511.

I ended up uninstalling both versions and letting Visual Studio install the necessary package to run my project, which ended up being version 10.0.26624.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this helps anyone, it appears like the newer versions of Windows SDK installer remove previous versions correctly, but somehow fail to remove their entries from Add/Remove Programs list. In my case, I had as many as 7 entries in there. I sorted them on installation date and started removing one by one, starting with the oldest. For every entry, I just received the following error message:

[image]

I kept removing them till I was left with the latest version only. Uninstalling this one brings up proper installer window instead of this error message, at which point you can cancel uninstallation process.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for me, I actually went through  the full uninstall process for one of the two sdks I had.

Comment: Neither here, but thanks for the heads up. These files can chew up some serious disk space!